# Keep css zoom value through cookie issue

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am having an issue with my code below that I am not able to solve by myself.

I am having an issue with my code below that I am not able to solve by myself.

I have a function to zoom in/out which is triggered by the buttons which works fine. I save the value on increase/decrease in a cookie to retain the zoom when switching of page on the website. That also works as it should, but once I have switched page the in/out function does not work anymore.

I thought it was due to too much decimals on cookie values or to the typeof cookie value… but I am not able to figure out why my code doesn't work.

So any help would be appreciated :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#zoom-in').click(function() {
        updateZoom(0.1);
    });

    $('#zoom-out').click(function() {
        updateZoom(-0.1);
    });

    function setCookie(name, value, days) {
        var d = new Date;
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*days);
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return v ? v[2] : null;
    }

    zoomLevel = getCookie('zoom_level');

    if (zoomLevel == null) {
      zoomLevel = 1;
    }

    $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });

    function updateZoom(zoom) {
        zoomLevel += zoom;
        //zoomLevel = parseFloat(zoomLevel).toFixed(1);
        //zoomLevel = parseInt(zoomLevel);
        if (zoomLevel >= 1) {
            $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
            setCookie('zoom_level', zoomLevel, 1);
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be caused by precision errors when doing floating point (decimal) calculations. I fix the issue as follow. I hope this can be help and save time to somebody :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Set - Get - Delete cookie function here 

let zoomLevel = 1;

if (getCookie('zoom_level')) {
    zoomLevel = getCookie('zoom_level')
};

$('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });

$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
    zoomLevel = (zoomLevel * 10 + 1) / 10;
    $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
    setCookie('zoom_level', zoomLevel, 1);
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
    zoomLevel = (zoomLevel * 10 - 1) / 10;
    if (zoomLevel >= 1) {
        $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
        setCookie('zoom_level', zoomLevel, 1);
    };
});

});
```